# Change System tray Icon in java

Tags: java, image, swing, packaging, system-tray

I just want to change the system tray Icon image for my application. I did 2 things -

Just changed the URL in the default program -

```
final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(createImage("images/Graph.png", "tray icon"));
```

Second try -

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/Graph.png");
final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(img, "Application Name", popup);
```

The application launches in both cases but no image is shown. Its a blank placeholder. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did the original program work ? You only changed the path for the icon ?

Comment: the bulb in the original program works. Ya i only changed the path of the icon in the first try.

Comment: Something seems wrong with your pathing then. If you are using the bulb example you should be able to just change the icon and have it working np. missing file? Try another file type? Case maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`images/Graph.png` is not a valid URL for an image located in your jar. Hence, I guess that `img` is null on your second try.

I suggest you this way :

```
//Get the URL with method class.getResource("/path/to/image.png")
URL url = System.class.getResource("/images/Graph.png");

//Use it to get the image
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);

final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(img, "Application Name", popup);
```

You shall also ensure that `images/` is in your classpath.

Comment: You dont need a jar to lunch the application also the pathing from running java someClass vs java -jar someJar.jar is different.

Comment: this works but without adding anything to class path. But why didn't the first try work ?

Comment: @Dan its the / in the path.

Comment: IMHO, it is a problem of path. You could try `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()` to know what is the current directory when you search images. With the method I gave you, you actually give the path to the image from the root of the classpath. That's why it also works even if the image is inside a jar.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you include the image file as the image is inside your `. jar`, use `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream`, try this:

```
 try {
    InputStream inputStream= ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/Graph.png");
//or getResourceAsStream("/images/Graph.png"); also returns inputstream

  BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
    final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(img, "Application Name", popup);
}
   catch (IOException e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works in the next way:

```
// URL: MyProject/src/MyGUI/check.png   
// Small icon on secondary taskbar
Image image= ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/MyGUI/check.png"));
trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "App name", popup);
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
```

### Results

[image]